# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for ProgressMonitorDialog

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to get the `ProgressMonitorDialog` to work, but for some reason it does not work in an E4 (4.7.2) application. It works standalone, though.

What I do: in a standard E3 compatibility handler I do the following:

```
        new ProgressMonitorDialog(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event)).run(false, false, monitor -> {
            monitor.beginTask("My Task", 20);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                monitor.worked(1);
            }
            monitor.done();
        });
```

When I execute the handler I get the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1600
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.ItemImpl.setEnabled(ItemImpl.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$1.run(AbstractContributionItem.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.updateItemEnablement(AbstractContributionItem.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolItemUpdater.updateContributionItems(ToolItemUpdater.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.subscribeTopicUpdateToolbarEnablement(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:289)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4889)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService$1.changed(EvaluationService.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activate(EclipseContext.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener$2.run(ShellActivationListener.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.activate(ShellActivationListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.handleEvent(ShellActivationListener.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1078)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1698)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2277)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4840)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1657)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5178)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.open(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.aboutToRun(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:480)
    at org.acme.project.MyHandler.execute(MyHandler.java:74)
```

If you try the code above, you will find that it works. Because I omittet the line that breaks the code:

```
DPIUtil.setDeviceZoom(100);
```

No matter where I put it, the above exception gets thrown when a dialog is opened. However I need the line because the current RCP still has the scaling tied to the display, and so I can't print when the primary monitor has scaling active. (For more information on *that issue*, I collected all my findings [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46660031/scaling-handled-differently-in-java-and-eclipse-framework).)

Is there any way to fix this problem? I assume other companies have the same problems with printing and scaling so there must be something I can do.